# Linux X260 special keys

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard, keyboard-layout, thinkpad

I am attempting to make use of my f4, f7-f12 special keys, but am unable to find event/key codes for them. I do have thinkpad_acpi, and am able to use f1-f3, f5-f6. Do people have suggestions no how I can find their identifiers, to map them? So far the closest information I have found was [here](https://www.corsac.net/X250/#keyboard), but neither KEY_SEARCH or XF86Search would let f10 do anything when bound.

Unfortunately `acpi_listen` doesn't see these keys. :( Neither does `xev`, `dmesg`, or `getscancodes`...

I am on debian sid, with kernel 4.6 manually added.

**EDIT 12JUL2016:**
My research has lead me to believe that this [bug/patch](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=114731) and this [acpi issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/ibm-acpi/mailman/message/34988427/) are related to why the keys don't work yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, shortly after my last edit (12JUL2016), I have found that a fix has been pushed on debian sid.

While not all of the keys show in `acpi_listen`, they do show in `xev` now.

- F4: XF86AudioMicMute
- F7: XF86Display
- F8: XF86WLAN
- F9: XF86Tools
- F10:XF86Search
- F11: XF86LaunchA
- F12: XF86Explorer